# .net vNext Fedora issue

Tags: asp.net, fedora, asp.net-core, libuv

I tried to install vNext on Fedora 20 following this tutorial: http://www.ganshani.com/blog/2014/12/shell-script-to-setup-net-on-linux/ but when I start HelloWeb example from aspnet github repo I get this message:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.loop_size () [0x00000] in :0 
      at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvLoopHandle.Init (Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv uv) [0x00000] in :0 
      at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.KestrelThread.ThreadStart (System.Object parameter) [0x00000] in :0 
    [root@localhost HelloWeb]# k kestrel
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.loop_size () [0x00000] in :0 
      at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvLoopHandle.Init (Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv uv) [0x00000] in :0 
      at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.KestrelThread.ThreadStart (System.Object parameter) [0x00000] in :0
```

I belive that problem is in wrong **libuv** library. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

try to follow the procedure explain [here](http://olivierlefebvre.tumblr.com/post/101523386694/asp-vnext-alpa4-on-ubuntu), I'd the same issue on ubuntu

Anyway I prefer to use [Firefly](https://github.com/aguacongas/firefly) which is much more performant

Comment: Thanks. I found solution. The libuv library was installed in /usr/lib instead in /usr/lib64.